# How can I read date ( timestamp ) from Cloud-Firestore?

Tags: java, date, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I have a ProfileFragment where I want to show the user's profile. I also added the birth date in Firestore and now I want to display it for the current user on his profile so, how can I do that? Do I have to convert it to a string or what should I do ? I tried to make it a string with .toString() but it isn't displayed.If I let it like that or make it a Date it will show me an error when I try to "setText" to the TextView variable.

```
TVbirthdate = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.birthdateinfo);
Timestamp birthResult = task.getResult().getTimestamp("Birth Date");
TVbirthdate.setText(birthResult.toDate());
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the `timestamp` to the actual date format first before using it on the `setText()` method. See sample converter function below:

```
private String getDate(long time) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
    String date = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", cal).toString();
    return date;
}
```

After converting, you can now set this date using the `setText()` method. See sample code below:

```
// birthResult here is the Timestamp object from Firestore
TVbirthdate.setText(getDate(birthResult));
```

If the above code is not possible for your use-case, you can also use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). See sample implementation below:

```
Date dataDate = birthResult.toDate();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
TVbirthdate.setText(sdf.format(dataDate));
```

Comment: I still have an error when I do this : "TVbirthdate.setText(getDate(birthResult));"  because I have to put an argument of type "long" as parameter and mine is a Timestamp ( birthResult ). Also, I need only the date, I don't want the time.

Comment: @Daiana I've updated my answer. I've added workaround for your use-case.